# Cross entropy of a random variable or a probability distribution function?

Tags: entropy, cross-entropy

I'm looking into the wikipedia page of cross entropy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_entropy

$$H(p,q)=-\sum_{x\in \mathcal{X}} p(x)\log q(x)$$

It can be written as $$H(p,q) = H(p) + D_{KL} (p||q)$$ where $H(p)$ stands for the entropy of $p$ (which is a probability distribution function here), and $D_{KL} (p||q)$ means the Kullback–Leibler divergence between $p$ and $q$.

But when I looked into the definition of entropy. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entropy_(information_theory)

It says it is the entropy of a random variable.
$$H(x) = -\sum P(X_i)log(P(X_i))$$

So it really baffles me, is it the entropy of a probability distribution function or the entropy of a random variable? If it is the latter case, what if there are more than one probability distribution function of $x$? Like $p$ and $q$ on the cross entropy case. If so, it should be the entropy of a probability distribution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that a [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable#Definition) $X$ is a measurable function $X:\Omega\to\mathbb R$ from a probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal F, p)$, where $\Omega$ is some set, $\mathcal F$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $\Omega$, and $p$ is a probability measure for $(\Omega, \mathcal F)$. The distribution is just the "push forward" of $p$ to $\mathbb R$. Thus, a random variable can never have two different distributions.

The cross-entropy $H(p,q)$ is defined for two different random variables, one with the distribution $p$ and the other with the distribution $q$. Those two random variables just happen to have the same image, but since they create different distributions on this image, they are different functions.

The entropy is a property of a random variable that is computed from its distribution, so sometimes people talk about the entropy of a distribution.

Comment: Thank you very much. You said they happen to have the same image. But the definition of cross entropy has $p(x)$ and $q(x)$? Which means these two probability distribution functions are of the same random variable? or should I think there are two random variables $X$ and Y, p(x) and q(x) stands for p(X=x) and q(Y=x)?

Comment: @user900476 correct